# In QGIS 2.8, how do I change the default yellow highlight select?

Tags: qgis

I would like to have only the outline of a property parcel turn yellow instead of the entire feature. Currently, any selected feature is entirely covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [bug report](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/4553) about your request. Unlucky it's not fixed at moment.

You could adjust the transparency to see the features inside.